# How to run ionic app on IOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic2

I open my ionic app folder then platforms->ios->HelloCordova.xcodeproj then 
it open in my Xcode and when I try to run the app get this two error

[image]

Comment: you're just build and running it right (cmd-R)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the useful commands for running ionic app in iOS device. 
1. Build app 
$ ionic build iOS 
2. Run app in simulator 
$ ionic emulate iOS 
3. Run app in device. (First attach developer certificates with appropriate project from XCode. You have to set these certificates from project **Navigators** in **Build Settings** tab)
$ ionic run ios --device

Comment: `ionic cordova run ios --device` does not work for iOS.